# Passing variable to jQuery SuperBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify SuperBox by Tim Motto http://toddmotto.com/introducing-superbox-the-reimagined-lightbox-gallery/ and want the ability to pass a variable to the script

What is the method for passing a variable to a jQuery script that uses the following syntax?
(code from html):

```
<script src="js/superbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
    // Call SuperBox
    $('.superbox').SuperBox();
    });
</script>
```

contents of superbox.js:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.SuperBox = function(options) {

    var superbox      = $('<div class="superbox-show"></div>');
    var superboxclose = $('<div class="superbox-close"></div>');

    superbox.append(superboxclose);

    return this.each(function() {

        $('.superbox-list').click(function() {

        if($('.superbox-current-img').css('opacity') == 0) {
            $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 1});
        }

        if ($(this).next().hasClass('superbox-show')) {
            superbox.toggle();
        } else {
            superbox.insertAfter(this).css({display: "block", "max-width": "94.6%"});
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:superbox.position().top - currentimg.width()
        }, 'medium');

        });

        $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-close', function() {
            $('.superbox-show').slideUp();
        });

    });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

As programmed, when the user clicks an image on the page it opens a div similar to how Google image search works. I want it to open a div but pass some data along for an AJAX call. In my html I have an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" data-id="13065">
```

and modified the the js file as follows:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.SuperBox = function(options) {

        var id            = $(this).data('id'); <!-- added -->
        alert(id);                              <!-- added -->
        var superbox      = $('<div class="superbox-show"></div>');
        var superboxclose = $('<div class="superbox-close"></div>');

        superbox.append(superboxclose);

        return this.each(function() {
            var id            = $(this).data('id');  <!-- added -->
            alert(id);                               <!-- added -->

            $('.superbox-list').click(function() {
                if($('.superbox-current-img').css('opacity') == 0) {
                    $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 1});
                }
    .....
    }
}
```

However, testing that data-id is passed along and defined, the alert box is empty in either instance.  What am I doing wrong?

**Revision**

For the sake of brevity, I left out some of the DOM.  From the prototype:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="superbox">
        <div class="superbox-list">
                <img blah, blah >
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Click on the image in a `div class="superbox-list"` within `div class="superbox-list"` and the jQuery fires.

Comment: You can always pass the ID in using the options object (I see you passing it in the SuperBox constructor method).

Comment: How does the `<a href="#" data-id="13065">` relate to the `$(".superbox")` element?

Comment: @lebelo - how do I pass something to the options object from the html using an <a> tag like above?